# Passing variables into LocationManagerDelegate class

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to pass in a String name into my LocationManagerDelegate class so that it will upload the updated location to Firebase, but I'm getting an "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments" error. I'm pretty new to Swift so I'm unsure of how I can do this properly.

```
struct ListView : View {
    var name = ""
    var geopoints : [String : GeoPoint]

    @State var managerDelegate = LocationManagerDelegate(name: name)
    @State var manager = CLLocationManager()

    var body : some View {
        VStack {
            Text(name)
        }.onAppear{
            self.manager.delegate = self.managerDelegate
            self.manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        }

    }
}

class LocationManagerDelegate : NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate{
    var name = ""

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == .denied{
            print("denied")
        }
        else{
            print("authorized")
            manager.requestLocation()
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let last = locations.last
        let db = Firestore.firestore()

        db.collection("locations").document("sharing").setData(["updates" : [name : GeoPoint(latitude: (last?.coordinate.latitude)!, longitude: (last?.coordinate.longitude)!)]], merge: true) {
            (err) in

            if err != nil {
                print((err?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            }
            print("success")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add explicit initialiser as below

```swift
class LocationManagerDelegate : NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var name = ""

    init(name: String) {    // << this one !!
       self.name = name
    }

    ...
```